# Call function from class without declaring name object

Tags: python, class, object

We have a Tree, each node is an object.

The function that this tree has are 3, `add(x);getmin();getmax()`

The tree works perfectly; for example if i write

```
a = Heap()
a.add(5)
a.add(15)
a.add(20)
a.getmin()
a.getmax()
```

the stack look like this `[5,15,20]`, now if i call `getmin()` it will print `min element = 5` and the stack will look like `[15,20]` and so on.

The problem comes now;

the professor asked us to submit two files which are already created: `main.py` and `minmaxqueue.py`

main.py starts like this `from minmaxqueue import add, getmin, getmax`, and then is has already a list of functions calls of the kind

```
add(5)
add(15)
add(20)
getmin()
getmax()
```

in order to make work my script i had to do `a=Heap()` and then call always `a.add(x)`. Since the TA's are going to run the script from a common file, i cant modify `main.py` such that it creates an object `a=Heap()`. It should run directly with `add(5)` and not with `a.add(5)`

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you interpreted the task from the professor correctly, it lacks the proper understanding of OOP. It would be possible to do that by declaring a module variable with the Heap in `minmaxqueue.py`. But that would be an awful solution. What you did is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your module to create a global `Heap` instance, and define functions that forward everything to that global instance. Like this:

```
class Heap(object):
    # all of your existing code

_heap = Heap()
def add(n):
    return _heap.add(n)
def getmin():
    return _heap.getmin()
def getmax():
    return _heap.getmax()
```

Or, slightly more briefly:

```
_heap = Heap()
add = _heap.add
getmin = _heap.getmin
getmax = _heap.getmax
```

If you look at the standard library, there are modules that do exactly this, like [`random`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py#l712). If you want to create multiple `Random` instances, you can; if you don't care about doing that, you can just call `random.choice` and it works on the hidden global instance.

Of course for `Random` it makes sense; for `Heap`, it's a lot more questionable. But if that's what the professor demands, what can you do?

Comment: And I would also point out to the professor that there is a flaw in his script that forces you to make ugly code.

Comment: @popovitsj: Maybe. This kind of API obviously doesn't make _nearly_ as much sense for `Heap` as for `Random`. But I'd be careful about how you go about telling the professor that he's stupid. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to do that more quickly:

```
def make_attrs_global(obj):
    for attr in dir(obj):
        if not attr.startswith('__'):
            globals()[attr] = getattr(obj, attr)
```

It makes all attributes of `obj` defined in global scope.
Just put this code at the end of your `minmaxqueue.py` file:

```
a = Heap()
make_attrs_global(a)
```

Now you should be able to call `add` directly without `a`. This is ugly but well...

Comment: Just use `make_attrs_global(Heap())` for even more quickly.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I know but I did not want to confuse him and maybe he wants to keep the reference to this Heap object.